# How to make page fully functional in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

In my code the iframe normally loads the first page of the embedded page, a CO2-Calculator. The problem I have now is that when opening the CO2-Calculator normally in the Browser, it works as intended but in the iframe when clicking on the Next button, I always land on an error page instead of the next question page.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Aswahl Tipps Projekte</title>
<link href="css/child.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=index.html" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").css("display", "none");
   $("body").fadeIn(800);
       $("a.transition").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         linkLocation = this.href;
         $("body").fadeOut(900, redirectPage);
      });
      function redirectPage() {
         window.location = linkLocation;
      }
});

let toggle = a => {
    let element = document.getElementById("rechner");
    let hidden = element.getAttribute("hidden");
    
    if (hidden) {
       element.removeAttribute("hidden");
       img.src="images/CO2-Rechner.png";
    } else {
       element.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
       img.src="images/beenden.png";
    }
  }


</script> 
    
</head>
    
<body>

    <img id="logo" src="images/wwf_logo.png" alt="Logo" width="140px" height="auto" />
        <div id="auswahl">
            <div id="informationprojekte">
                <a class="headprojekte" href="auswahl_diashows.html"><img src="images/head_projekte.png" alt="Info" width="700px" height="auto" /></a>
                <a class="buttonprojekte" href="auswahl_diashows.html"><img src="images/button_projekte.png" alt="Info" width="auto" height="60px" /></a>
            </div>
                <div id="informationtipps">
                    <a class="headprojekte" href="tipp_eins.html"><img src="images/head_tipps.png" alt="Info" width="700px" height="auto" /></a>
                    <a class="buttontipps" href="tipp_eins.html"><img class="info" src="images/Verbrauchertipps.png" alt="Info" width="auto" height="60px" /></a>
                    
                </div>
            
       <iframe id="rechner" src="https://www.klimarechner.wwf.de" sandbox="allow-top-navigation" loading="lazy" frameborder="0" hidden="hidden" > </iframe>
       <a onclick="toggle(this);" class="buttonrechner" ><img class="info" src="images/CO2-Rechner.png" alt="CO2-Rechner" width="auto" height="60px" /></a>

                    <a class="projekte" href="auswahl_diashows.html"><img src="images/thumb_projekte.jpg" alt="Projekte" width="950px" height="auto" /></a>
                         <a class="tipps"><img src="images/thumb_tipps.jpg" alt="Tipps" width="950px" height="auto" /></a>
                </div>
                    <div id="menue">
                        <a class="zurueck" href="startseite.html"><img src="images/zurueck.png" alt="Mehr erfahren" width="220px" height="auto" /></a>
                    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    }

video.v1 {
    width: 1920px;
    z-index: auto;
}

#startanimation {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1920px;
    margin-top: 0;
 
}

/* Menue Startseite */

#menue {
    position: absolute;
     margin-top: 840px;
}

a.FilmNeuStarten {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1340px;
    margin-top: 130px;  
    z-index: 1;
}

a.mehrErfahren {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1340px;
    margin-top: 74px;   
    z-index: 1;
}

a.zurueck {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1580px;
    margin-top: 100px;  
    z-index: auto;
}

/* Mehr erfahren */

#auswahl {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 535px;
    margin: 240px 0 0 0;

}

a.projekte {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: auto;
}

a.tipps {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 970px; 
    z-index: auto;
}

#informationprojekte {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#informationtipps {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 1020px;
    z-index: 1;
}

a.headprojekte {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

a.buttonprojekte {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    z-index: 1;
}

a.buttontipps {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    z-index: 1;
}

a.buttonrechner {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.buttonrechner {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Sonstiges */

#headline  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;   
}

#anweisung  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 755px;
    
}


/* uebergreifend */



a:active {
    opacity: 0.1;
    
}

#rechner {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    margin: -250px 0 0 0;
   
}
.rechner {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
   
  
}
```

I tried all sorts of sandbox attribute possibilities and combing through stackoverflow and other sites for help, but haven't found anything yet that could make it work.

Comment: Despite the possible CO issues, anchors have no `img` property.